# Calling javascript function from Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

Tried to call a javascript popup window using ColdFusion. Have not been able to do it.

The ColdFusion code is straight forward

```
<cfif notpaid>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    notpaid();
    </script>
</cfif>
```

It will pop up a window if a person is "notpaid".  I tried it with `alert()` and it popup the alert box so the problem is not with this ColdFusion code.

One of the associated embedded javascripts is written as:

```
modalWin = new CreateModalPopUpObject();
modalWin.SetLoadingImagePath("/dev/images/loading.gif");
modalWin.SetCloseButtonImagePath("/dev/images/remove.gif");

function notpaid() {
    modalWin.Draggable=false;
    modalWin.ShowURL('https://www.sample.com/sample.htm', 320, 350, "Heading");
}
function HideModalWindow() {
    modalWin.HideModalPopUp();
    window.document.forms[1].submit();
}
```

The `modalWin.ShowURL` is the function that display the popup window and is proven working when it is associated with clicking, i.e. user click on a button and it will pop up the window.

In the new scenario, I am using ColdFusion to call without user interaction, but it won't pop up the window.  I believe the problem lies with the javascript function `notpaid()`. I have tried different ways to no avail.  I seen people talking about CF being server-side and javascript being client-side, but I do not know how to make the connection.  I know with some proper code, it can be done.  What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Likely possibilities A) Either the variable is false, so the CFIF block isn't hit. Add a <CFELSE> Message not displayed </CFIF> so you know if that's the problem B) A javascript error is occurring. Check your browser's debugging console for errors C) The code is being used somewhere that doesn't generate any output, like a CFC with output=false.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally figured it out.  By changing the "function notpaid()"  to:

```
notpaid = function() {
    modalWin.Draggable=false;
    modalWin.ShowURL("https://www.sample.com/sample.htm", 320, 350, "Heading");
}
```

and the pop up worked.  Don't know why, but it did the trick.

Comment: Because in `function notpaid()...` you are creating a function named `notpaid`, but with `cfif notpaid`, you are looking for some sort of variable or cf object. When you create `notpaid = function()...` you're actually creating a variable named `notpaid`, so `cffif` sees that it exists.